# Trying to install bower in mac but getting semver-utils@1.1.1 issue

Tags: bower

I typed `sudo npm install` -g bower getting this issue again and again

```
/usr/local/bin/bower -> /usr/local/lib/node_modules/bower/bin/bower
bower@1.7.2 /usr/local/lib/node_modules/bower
└── semver-utils@1.1.1
```

Comment: What is the error you are getting?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This doesn't look like an error at all. `semver-utils` is a library required by bower after 1.7.1.

Maybe run `bower` in the command line and show us the error you're getting.